# What should I look at if I want to buy RAM to my PC?

Tags: memory, compatibility

I have 2GB (2 x 1GB !Rx8 PC2 - 5300U - 555 - 12) on my PC (Windows 7 64-bit version):

http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=3459243&swLangOid=18&swEnvOid=1093

I want to know how many GB of RAM can I set on my PC, and what modal I need to buy? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is off-topic because it is asking for hardware buy recommendations. A common mistake made by new members is failing to reading what is [on-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) before posting a question. You should become familiar with the site by taking a *[tour]* and reading *[ask]*.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I though that this question should be here! my fault!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOLVED!**

Finally I got more information about RAM, and I know right now what type of RAM I can reach 8GB It seems...

http://www.marmaxcomputers.com/img/180216113329HP_Compaq_dc7800.pdf

I know that's an ancient system... but I'm helping people who needs to improve his PC, with a minimum requeriments, to keep on doing dialy tasks better, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Click on that link you yourself supplied.
To the left there is the upgrade section. That links to an entire page on the subject of possible memory upgrades for this machine.

Why you would want to upgrade such an ancient system (8-9 years old) is beyond me though.
It's only matter of time something else on this old machine either fails because of age, or is the next bottleneck in performance.
In most cases a new computer (with more RAM, a SSD and faster CPU) is a bit more expensive but provides a far better user-experience in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, is your operating system 32-bit or 64-bit? Remember that if you have a 32-bit version of Windows, you can only use up to 4 GB of ram, and there will be no point in adding more,

If you have a 64-bit operating system then you can add as much as you want (not really, but I doubt you would pass the ram limit)

If you only have 2GB now then you could certainly add at least 2 GB more either way  provided you have the room,